# Timer class and calling methods with passing parameter

Tags: c#, timer, delegates, action

I have a method that uses Timer class to call on a method and execute it on specific intervals.

```
private Timer tmr = new Timer();
     public void WorkAtInterval(long interval, Action<object> work)
                {
                    //heartbeat in miliseconds
                    tmr.Interval = interval;
                    tmr.Start();
                    tmr.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(work);
                }
```

I have defined the function that has to be called like this:

```
private static void WorkSample (object interval)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The interval is: {0}",interval);
        }
```

and then eventually in my Main function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HeartBeat heart = new HeartBeat();

            var interval = heart.HeartBeatInterval;

            heart.WorkAtInterval(interval,sampleWork(interval));

            Console.Read();
        }
```

unfortunately, this even is not compiling. I am not that great with delegates.Any recommendation on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda expression:

```
heart.WorkAtInterval(interval, x => WorkSample(interval));
```

Comment: The problem is when I pass the method work in the WorkAtInterval method as tmr.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(work), I have the error there that says "Method name is expected"

Comment: @user843681 That's because `ElapsedEventHandler` and `Action<object>` don't have the same signature.  You'll need to address that.

Comment: @servy I am aware of that, the problem is that when I create the same signature as ElapsedEventHandler, I can not pass a parameter to the function that I want to be executed anymore.

Comment: @user843681 You can if you do what this answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is like this. The signature of the WorkAtInterval has to meet the signature ElapsedEventHandler. And then in the Main function the calling has to be done properly by anonymous function.

```
public void WorkAtInterval(long interval, Action<object,EventArgs> work)
            {
                //heartbeat in miliseconds
                tmr.Interval = interval;
                tmr.Start();
                tmr.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(work);
            }

private static void sampleWork(object interval)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The interval is: {0}",interval);
        }  


static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HeartBeat heart = new HeartBeat();

            var interval = heart.HeartBeatInterval;

            heart.WorkAtInterval(interval,(o,s) => sampleWork(interval));

            Console.Read();
        }
```